# Windows 7 Cannot Delete a shortcut named $NtUninstallKB48959$

Tags: windows-7

I have `Window 7` `64 bit` OS in my laptop. I did reinstall the OS yesterday which moved my old windows, documents, program files folder into Windows.old folders. I tried to delete everything in that folder considering to save space. I could delete everything but shortcut named "$NtUninstallKB48959$" in the below mentioned path.

"C:\Windows.old\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-276155270-2342152204-2275300765-1000\$RGEAPLQ"

That shortcut links to "C:\Windows\System32\config".
So whenever I try to delete it gives error as below

**Delete Confirmation**
[image: Delete Confirmation]

**Error**
[image: Error]

And the shortcut is Non-editable.

[image]

I tried these below steps but none of them worked out.

**1. Run a Complete Anti-Virus scan by Avast.**

**2. Ensure running with full Administrative rights.**

**3. Removed junk files by cleanmgr.**

**4. Ensure I am the owner of the folder and subfolders ('Folder->Right Click->Properties->Security tab->Advanced->Owner->Edit->Change owner to->Select my username->Checked Replace owner on subcontainers and objects')**

**5. Run System File Checker (Run cmd with administrative rights->chkdsk /f/r)**

**6. Run Disk Check Tool (Run cmd with administrative rights->chkdsk /f/r)**

**7. Checked whether drivers are up to date by Device Manager**

Comment: May I know why it has been downvoted? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try acessing the properties of the file : Left click > Properties 
Then try to edit the shortcut target value and save. Then try again to delete